# SwiftUI: How to set background color for textfield

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image: description]

When I select the textfield, it gets rid of its background color where the text is supposed to be. I attached an image showing the Card holder textfield for example. Maybe it's just a bug? Here is my code for the "CardHolderView":

Reproducing the error:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9384715557, green: 0.9561783671, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9384715557, green: 0.9561783671, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(UIScreen.main.bounds.height < 750 ? .vertical : .init()) {
                ZStack {
                    Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9384715557, green: 0.9561783671, blue: 1, alpha: 1)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    CardHolderView(name: $name)
                        .padding()
                }
                .padding(.top, 60)
                .navigationBarTitle("Payment data", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {}) { Image("left-arrow") })
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct CardHolderView: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Card holder")
            TextField("Your name and surname", text: $name)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see that issue pasting your code into a test app.  Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi, so I was able to reproduce the error and edited into my post. So the init() near the top where I am setting the UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor is what's causing it for some reason. The reason why I need it is to cover up the white bounce background that's caused by the scrollview in smaller devices

Comment: Don't  modify the appearance of `UIScrollView`; Just set the `.background` modifier of the `ScrollView`. `UIAppearance` is a global change and pretty brute-force.

Comment: That was so simple I don't know why I didn't even think of that. Anyways, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `UIAppearance` to set the background color of the `ScrollView`; You can use use `.background` modifier on it.

`UIAppearance` makes global changes and can have unintended consequences.